# Sharepoint List Service

Tags: infopath

Respected sir,

in my browser following url works file "http ://techlab-server/sites/testsagar/Lists/_vti_bin/lists.asmx" but if i append ?WSDl at end of url to view service description it does not display.
also i have tried to use Service in infopath 2010 but not work. so please help me.

Actualy i want to make a From using Infopath 2010 and After Publish it to sharepoint Library whaen i fill that form and submit then Data should be Stored in Sharepoint List without any programming using only with infopath.

Answer (score 2):

Sagar,

I think you have got the location for the service wrong.

```
http://techlab-server/sites/testsagar/Lists/_vti_bin/lists.asmx
```

Should in fact be

```
http://techlab-server/sites/testsagar/_vti_bin/lists.asmx
```

The _vti_bin/ folder is always virtually linked directly under the Web that you want to access the data for, rather than the Lists/ subfolder therein.

Incidentally, to solve your problem using InfoPath, you shouldn't need to use Web Services directly. Assuming your SharePoint Server has InfoPath Forms Services enabled then you should be able to publish the form directly to the requisite Form Library on the server and use the built in InfoPath Rules to Submit the Form to the library.

Tim

Answer (score 0):

the service you are trying to use is a **REST** service and not web service.

Check it [here](http://www.synergyonline.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=35) how to use this.

Hope it helps,

Andrew

Comment: Andrew, I think you misread his question. He wants to use the Lists.asmx service which is a SOAP Web Service, and not ListData.svc which is the REST Web Service. Regardless, REST is just an architectural pattern which applies to many things including web services. Therefore the ListData.svc RESTful service is indeed a web service!